# Getting docker stats programmatically

Tags: python, docker

I am using docker-py and trying to get docker stats. But I am unable to get any API for returning stats for particular container. Is there a REST API or any other way to programmatically get the stats ?

```
>>> cli = docker.Client(base_url="tcp://xxxxx:2375", version='1.21')
>>> cli.containers() >> gives the right o/p
>>> cli.containers.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

>>> docker.version
'1.10.6'
```

Comment: What "stats" are you looking for?

Comment: CPU usage, memory usage etc.

Comment: See [`Container.stats`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.stats)

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for [`Container.stats`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.Container.stats).

Comment: thanks. I am using this and I get info. 
s = cli.stats("<container id>", stream=False)
Looking at how to make the CPU usage as % instead of a huge number.

Comment: I am getting the CPU % via https://github.com/TomasTomecek/sen/blob/master/sen/util.py#L158

Answer (score 4):

1. Get stats for a particular container name example: "monitoring-tinydb".
   Note: change this container name with your desired container id or name.

   ```
   import docker
   client = docker.from_env()
   container = client.containers.get("monitoring-tinydb")
   status = container.stats(decode=None, stream = False)
   print(status)
   ```
2. Get stats for all containers running in the docker host

   ```
   import docker
   client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix:///var/run/docker.sock')
   for containers in client.containers.list():
       print(containers.stats(decode=None, stream = False))
   ```